# ReactJS: TypeError: this.props is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is App.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Todo from './Todo';
import Form from './Form';

class App extends Component {
  state= {
    list: [
      {
        title: "Take out trash",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        title: "Take dog for walk",
        id: 2
      },
      {
        title: "Doctor appointment",
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  };
  
  prevItemId=3;


  handleAddPlayer=(name)=> {
    this.setState( prevState=> {
      return {
        players: [
          ...prevState.players,
          {
            name,
            score: 0,
            id: this.prevPlayerId+=1
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header/>
        <Todo 
          number={this.state.list.length} 
          list={this.state.list}
        />
        <Form addItem={this.handleAddItem}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

Here is the form component (Form.js)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Form extends Component {
  
  state= {
    value: ''
  }

  handleChange=(e)=> {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit= (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addItem(this.state.value);
    this.setState({value: ''})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          List Item:
          <input type="text" name="name" value= {this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    )
  }

}

export default Form
```

In Forms.JS I keep getting an error that this.props.addItem is not a function. I understand there are many forums on this topic, but I can't figure out what's wrong. I'm trying to add a liste item to the App state when on a submit event, with the handleSubmit function

Comment: `<Form addItem={this.handleAddItem}/>` but the function is named `handleAddPlayer`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the function name in `App.js` :

```
  <Form addItem={this.handleAddPlayer}/>
```